HMR is not implemented for module chunk format yet
I've converted my webpack project to output ES6:
    experiments: {
      outputModule: true
    },
    output: {
      library: {
        type: 'module'
      }
    },

Now, when I run in dev mode (webpack serve --open),  as soon as I make and save a change in a watched file, the terminal spits out the error message "Error: HMR is not implemented for module chunk format yet". Thinking I could solve this by just avoiding chunk format, I disabled my splitChunks section. But the error persists.
Clearly, chunking is not the same thing as code splitting. My build is still producing chunk files, just not as many without the splitChunks section. Is there a way to disable chunk production entirely? Produce one single output file? And is that even a potential solution to this error? And if not, what other options do I have?
